# Помогите с гридами пожалуйста

Tags: css, css-grid

Как сделать на гридах, чтоб было 3 колонки, но в 2 и 3 колонке было по 4 элемента.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Может кто-то знает как на гридах удачнее эту секцию позиционировать? Думал, будет что то вроде такого (здесь 1 — блок грида):

```
1   1  1

    1  1

    1  1

1   1  1
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы имеете ввиду что-то подобное этому?

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">
    <h1>Title 1</h1>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <h1>Title 2</h1>
    <div class="block-2">
      <h2>Title 1</h2>
      <p>Text....</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block-2">
      <h2>Title 2</h2>
      <p>Text....</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block-2">
      <h2>Title 3</h2>
      <p>Text....</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block-2">
      <h2>Title 4</h2>
      <p>Text....</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <h1>Title 3</h1>
    <div class="block-2">
      <h3>Title 1</h3>
      <p>Text....</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block-2">
      <h3>Title 2</h3>
      <p>Text....</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block-2">
      <h3>Title 3</h3>
      <p>Text....</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block-2">
      <h3>Title 4</h3>
      <p>Text....</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: да,только первая колонка на 2

Comment: хочу разделить на 2 части текст

Comment: а как обратиться к кастомному гриду?например хочу чтобы текст был разбит на 2 части по 2ум гридам? как грид сетка узнает,что тут я хочу разбить текст,а тут нет?разбивать дивами?по количеству гридов?

Comment: нет не получилось.не то я имел в виду другое.ты сделал блоки в 3 гридах.а я хотел чтобы в каждом гриде было содержимое

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста что вы подразумеваете под гридами? Тут только 1 грид и в нем есть 3 колонки. Вы написали что вам надо грид с 3 колонками и во 2 и 3-тей колонке было по 4 элемента, я что то не так понял?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.grid-main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 50px);
}

.block-1 {
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}

.block-2 {
  grid-row: 3 / 5;
}

.grid-main div {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<section class="grid-main">
  <div class="block-1">asdasd</div>
  <div class="block-2">sdasdsad</div>
  <div class="block-3">2</div>
  <div class="block-4">3</div>
  <div class="block-5">4</div>
  <div class="block-6">1</div>
  <div class="block-7">2</div>
  <div class="block-8">3</div>
  <div class="block-9">4</div>
  <div class="block-10">4</div>
</section>
```